# Should/can I submit to the same journal and explain the situation asking for another review?

Tags: publications, mathematics, paper-submission

Recently I got a rejection of my research article from a mathematical journal. The referee report says "the results are correct but it has not motivation why should we care such results".

Now I have a got an idea and applied those results of my research paper to make a link with some interesting results of great interest.

My question-

Should/can I submit to the same journal with same Editor and  explain the situation asking for another review ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, only if you can show within the cover letter (or maybe by some changes within the manuscript) that either:

1. a significant aspect of your work in the original submission was misunderstood/neglected/misinterpreted or simply the process of the review (by the reviewers) was not objectively addressing a flaw in your work, or
2. you can provide a strong argument based on the points aroused by the reviewers,

then I would suggest preparing a convincing cover letter and resubmiting the manuscript.
The important point is that for the resubmission after rejection, you have to convince the editor why the first decision made by her/him could and should change. Since your manuscript was already reviewed once, the editor was interested in your work in the first place, so making an argument wouldn't hurt. Based on the response you got initially, this process is just a scientific argument and even if you get a second rejection because the editor does not see the situation the way you do, nobody will hold a grudge :)

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer

Answer (score 2):

No, you should not submit the paper to the same journal. The referee report is only one piece of information that helped the editor make the decision. You most probably do not know about other reports or opinions. Send it somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion. But it went under 6-7 months review

Comment: @MAS: 6-7 months support my answer. During this time, the Editor probably got a lot of information about the paper.

Comment: I do not recall that there was much relation between the time taken and the information garnered. But that is anecdotal.

Comment: @erstwhileeditor: For example, 6-7 months may mean that the Editor sent the paper to several people who refused refereeing. The reasons for refusal may be relevant to the quality of the paper. Of course everything depends on the field of research, on the journal and on the Editor. I can only rely on my experience as  an Editor of several journals.

Answer (score 2):

Note that some journals will not accept a resubmission of a rejected article and will simply reject it. In that case, you are wasting everyone's time by resubmitting there.

But absent such a rule you can certainly resubmit to the journal and it is possible that you will get a different outcome. But it is up to them what happens. The chances for a happy outcome increase, of course, if you have made sufficient changes to satisfy the reviewers. You might point that out to the editor to avoid a desk reject. A sentence or two will do.

Comment: Thanks. According to review report, my results are correct but it lacks motivation. I have found some good places to relate my results now. Thats why I am thinking to write a cover letter mentioning the previous submission number and a reason why  I am resubmitting. Just one question-Is there any chance that the paper will be assigned to same Editor and the same Referee ?

Comment: Yes, there is a chance. Probably a good chance, but it is up to the policies of the journal how resubmissions are handled. It is probably more efficient for them to send it to the same people. Alternatively they could seek a wider set of views. It is up to them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your opinion

Comment: @MAS probably should contact the editor for his or her position regarding resubmissions. This would likely save a lot of time for everyone.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero, I know the managing editor who primarily assigned the editor. So I don't know who was the editor.